# How Optimize this complex sql query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have the following SQL Query running in a msaccess database query, that takes several seconds,4 or 5 seconds in a good machines. but in the client machine takes many more...I have to optimize this query. 
I try making index in some tables like table Lins and MKT .. And seems to get a little better, 
The problem is that I have 8 querys like this running one after the other.. and its gettin really slow with more than 400.000 records

```
SELECT LINs.LIN,
       Sum(VentasDet.Cantidad) AS SumaDeCantidad
FROM ((
         (SELECT *
          FROM ventas
          WHERE (CBTE='COT'
                 OR CBTE='FCA'
                 OR CBTE='FCB'
                 OR CBTE='PR'
                 OR CBTE='RTO'
                 OR CBTE='TK')
            AND (Suc=0
                 OR Suc=1
                 OR Suc=2
                 OR Suc=4
                 OR Suc=5)
            AND (Caja=0
                 OR Caja=1
                 OR Caja=2)
            AND (PRDO='12-2017'
                 OR PRDO='11-2017'
                 OR PRDO='10-2017'
                 OR PRDO='09-2017')
            AND (MKT=1
                 OR MKT=2
                 OR MKT=3
                 OR MKT=4
                 OR MKT=5) ) AS Ventas
       INNER JOIN
         (SELECT *
          FROM VentasDet
          WHERE LIN<>'0-'
            AND LIN<>'1AS'
            AND LIN<>'1VF'
            AND LIN<>'NEW'
            AND LIN<>'OSE'
            AND LIN<>'OLJ'
            AND LIN<>'OS-O' ) AS VentasDet ON (Ventas.Numero = VentasDet.Numero)
       AND (Ventas.Suc = VentasDet.Suc)
       AND (Ventas.CBTE = VentasDet.CBTE))
      INNER JOIN
        (SELECT Codigo,
                MaMi
         FROM Clis
         WHERE MaMi=0
           OR MaMi=1
           OR MaMi=2 ) AS Clis ON Ventas.Cli = Clis.Codigo)
INNER JOIN LINs ON VentasDet.LIN = LINs.Codigo
GROUP BY VentasDet.LIN,
         LINs.LIN
ORDER BY Sum(VentasDet.Cantidad) DESC
```

Comment: Maybe create twp or three views?

Comment: avoid sub-queries and use temp tables and cursors instead

Comment: Is this a JET/ACE database?

Comment: How many records are in each of the tables: Ventas, VentasDets, Clis, Lins?

Comment: Is the VentasDet.LIN necessary in the group by clause?

Comment: Is it necessary to join Ventas to VentasDet on all three fields: Numero, Suc and CBTE? I don't know what Suc and CBTE are but it sounds like denormalised data which shouldn't be included in joins. Admittedly I have no understanding of your schema so I'm just asking questions to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below to see if it make any difference?
1. make a middle table to join CBTE;
2. make a middle table VentasDet;

```
create table CBTE (CBTE varchar(3));
insert into CBTE values('COT', 'FCA', 'FCB', 'PR','RTO', 'TK');


create table LIN (LIN varchar(4));
insert into LIN values('0-','1AS','1VF','NEW','OSE','OLJ','OS-O');


( SELECT *
          FROM VentasDet V
         left join LIN L on v.Lin=L.Lin where L.Lin is null) AS VentasDet
```

Comment: IMHO I would expect the join to require a comparison to each value in those tables for each row in the main table, which seems no less expensive than doing those comparisons as a where clause against literals (probably more). Could you please explain how this works better?